# Match every record only once in a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. The first `inv` containing records of invoices, the second containing `payments`. I want to match the payments in the `inv` table by `inv_amount` and `inv_date`. There might be more than one invoice with the same amount on the same day and also more than one payment of the same amount on the same day.

The payment should be matched with the first matching invoice and every payment must only be matched once.

This is my data:

Table `inv`

```
 inv_id | inv_amount |  inv_date  | inv_number
--------+------------+------------+------------
      1 |         10 | 2018-01-01 |          1
      2 |         16 | 2018-01-01 |          1
      3 |         12 | 2018-02-02 |          2
      4 |         14 | 2018-02-03 |          3
      5 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          3
      6 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          5
      7 |          5 | 2018-02-04 |          6
      8 |         40 | 2018-02-04 |          7
      9 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          8
     10 |         19 | 2018-02-05 |          9
     11 |         20 | 2018-02-05 |         10
     12 |         20 | 2018-02-07 |         11
```

Table `pay`

```
 pay_id | pay_amount |  pay_date
--------+------------+------------
      1 |         10 | 2018-01-01
      2 |         12 | 2018-02-02
      4 |         19 | 2018-02-04
      3 |         14 | 2018-02-03
      5 |          5 | 2018-02-04
      6 |         19 | 2018-02-04
      7 |         19 | 2018-02-05
      8 |         20 | 2018-02-07
```

My Query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (inv.inv_id) inv.inv_id,
    inv.inv_amount,
    inv.inv_date,
    inv.inv_number,
    pay.pay_id
   FROM ("2016".pay
     RIGHT JOIN "2016".inv ON (((pay.pay_amount = inv.inv_amount) AND (pay.pay_date = inv.inv_date))))
  ORDER BY inv.inv_id
```

resulting in:

```
 inv_id | inv_amount |  inv_date  | inv_number | pay_id
--------+------------+------------+------------+--------
      1 |         10 | 2018-01-01 |          1 |      1
      2 |         16 | 2018-01-01 |          1 |
      3 |         12 | 2018-02-02 |          2 |      2
      4 |         14 | 2018-02-03 |          3 |      3
      5 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          3 |      4
      6 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          5 |      4
      7 |          5 | 2018-02-04 |          6 |      5
      8 |         40 | 2018-02-04 |          7 |
      9 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          8 |      6
     10 |         19 | 2018-02-05 |          9 |      7
     11 |         20 | 2018-02-05 |         10 |
     12 |         20 | 2018-02-07 |         11 |      8
```

The record `inv_id = 6` should not match with `pay_id = 4` for it would mean that payment 4 was inserted twice

Desired result:

```
inv_id | inv_amount |  inv_date  | inv_number | pay_id
--------+------------+------------+------------+--------
      1 |         10 | 2018-01-01 |          1 |      1
      2 |         16 | 2018-01-01 |          1 |
      3 |         12 | 2018-02-02 |          2 |      2
      4 |         14 | 2018-02-03 |          3 |      3
      5 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          3 |      4
      6 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          5 |        <- should be empty**
      7 |          5 | 2018-02-04 |          6 |      5
      8 |         40 | 2018-02-04 |          7 |
      9 |         19 | 2018-02-04 |          8 |      6
     10 |         19 | 2018-02-05 |          9 |      7
     11 |         20 | 2018-02-05 |         10 |
     12 |         20 | 2018-02-07 |         11 |      8
```

Disclaimer: Yes I asked that question yesterday with the original data but someone pointed out that my sql was very hard to read. I, therefore, tried to create a cleaner representation of my problem.

For convenience, here's an SQL Fiddle to test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/018d7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the example I think I've got the query for you:

```
WITH payments_cte AS (
    SELECT
        payment_id,
        payment_amount,
        payment_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY payment_amount, payment_date ORDER BY payment_id) AS payment_row
    FROM payments
), invoices_cte AS (
    SELECT
        invoice_id,
        invoice_amount,
        invoice_date,
        invoice_number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_amount, invoice_date ORDER BY invoice_id) AS invoice_row
    FROM invoices
)
SELECT invoice_id, invoice_amount, invoice_date, invoice_number, payment_id
FROM invoices_cte
LEFT JOIN payments_cte
    ON payment_amount = invoice_amount
    AND payment_date = invoice_date
    AND payment_row = invoice_row
ORDER BY invoice_id, payment_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the edit. I just saw that the data was in the wrong order. I updated the post and the sqlfiddle. However, in your query there are records missing. There is no inv_id 3,6 and12. I updated the post with the desired result.

Comment: @user2626227 I've updated the query, I think this does exactly what you're looking for :)

Comment: thank you for the updated query. However, with this query pay_id 4 is matched with invoice_id 6 rather than the first possibility invoice_id 5. I inserted some of my real data and used your query. sqlfiddle.com/#!17/72ee1/1. As you can see payment_id 6201 is not where it is supposed to be and the payment_id 6212 and 6218 are completely out of order. I think maybe what I am trying to do is not possible with a sql query. payments should match the records on date and amount with invoices from top to bottom and and randomly where amount and date match.

Comment: It's probably still possible with Common Table Expressions (with queries)  but those are a tad harder to write and I'm a bit strapped for time.

Comment: @leu I've updated the answer again, this should take care of all of the edge cases as well by uniquely comparing all duplicates as well.